# How to fetch a Backbone Collection from sequelize-restful-extended in one call

Tags: rest, backbone.js, sequelize.js

I have a model called Instance which works fine.

```
define([], function(){
     return Backbone.Model.extend({

         urlRoot:'/api/Instances',
         parse:function(content){
            return content.data; 
         }    
        });
});
```

My REST at here

```
http://localhost:3000/api/Instances/1
```

returns this

```
{"status":"success","data":{"id":1,"name":"bangladesh","write":null,"read":null,"createdAt":"2015-09-01T23:03:16.000Z","updatedAt":"2015-09-01T23:03:16.000Z","UserId":1}}
```

hence the *parse* function in my model. All good so far.

If I just call

```
http://localhost:3000/api/Instances
```

Then I get a block of all my records,

```
{"status":"success","count":212,"data":[
{"id":1,"name":"bangladesh","write":null,"read":null,"createdAt":"2015-09-01T23:03:16.000Z","updatedAt":"2015-09-01T23:03:16.000Z","UserId":1},
{"id":2,"name":"abqride","write":null,"read":null,"createdAt":"2015-09-01T23:03:58.000Z","updatedAt":"2015-09-01T23:03:58.000Z","UserId":1},
....
```

And my collection code is just this

```
define(['models/instance.js'], function(Model){
     return Backbone.Collection.extend({
         url:'/api/Instances',
         model:Model,
         parse:function(content){
            return content.data; 
         }
     })
});
```

The above code for the Collection will create 212 models. I've checked that with an initialise function in the model just to see if it was being called OK with the right data, and it is.

But in my view code when I go

```
          this.collection.each(function(model) {
              console.log("model id="+model.get("id")+" count="+count++);
              out+=model.get("id")+"="+model.get("name")+"<br>";
            });
```

there's nothing in these models, but there are 212 of them, I just get "undefined=null
" 212 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see three options, two of which involve customizing the use of Backbone: 1. Calling `collection.sync` manually and then executing custom code afterward, 2. Passing a custom option in the initial `collection.fetch()` and looking for it in the Model `parse()` method.

These two options don't solve the problem at the source, however, since the concern is at the initial response level.  In order to apply a response-level filter to your data, try overriding `Backbone.ajax()` before starting your application:

```
Backbone.ajax = function () {
  var settings = arguments[1] || arguments[0]; // jQuery.ajax(url[, settings])
  var success = settings.success;
  settings.success = function (data, status, xhr) {
    if (success) { success(data.data, status, xhr); }
  };
  return Backbone.$.ajax.apply(Backbone.$, arguments);
};
```